# open tooltip for latest point on ng2-line chart on chart load

Tags: angular, charts, linechart, ng2-charts

I am using the ng2 line chart with the tooltip feature enabled. I want to show a tooltip programmatically on the latest point once the chart load is completed.

I looked around for solutions and found some solutions to manually creating a hover event by capturing the location of the point of interest which I am avoiding. I also searched for a better approach but couldn't find one.

Below is my code and config data. Any other approach which solves the problem will be helpful.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ChartDataSets} from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import 'hammerjs';
import * as zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';
import { OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss']
})

export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, {read: {selector: 'chart'}, static: false}) baseChart: BaseChartDirective;

  constructor(
    private hs: HelperService,
    private marketService: MarketrateService,
    ) { }
    public lineChartOptions: any
    public lineChartPlugins = [zoomPlugin]
    public lineChartDataSets: ChartDataSets[] = []

    ngOnInit() {
      this.lineChartDataSets = [{
        data: [],
        // label: 'Buy Price',
        // backgroundColor: "#2072ef",
        // borderColor: '#2072ef',
        type: 'line',
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        borderWidth: 2,
      }]
      this.lineChartOptions = {
        showTooltip: true,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        responsive: true,
        fill: false,
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
        },
        hover: {
          mode: 'nearest',
          intersect: true,
          onHover: function(e) {
            e.target.style.cursor = 'move'
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: false,
              labelString: 'Time',
            },
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              min: 0,
              tooltipFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm',
              displayFormats: {
                // 'second': 'MMM DD, hh:mm A',
                'second': 'DD/MM/YY HH:mm',
                'hour': 'HH:mm',
                'day': 'MMM D',
              },
              round: 'second',
              unit: 'hour',
            },
            distribution: 'series',
            ticks: {
              source: 'data',
              beginAtZero: false,
              maxTicksLimit: 7,
              autoSkip: true,
              maxRotation: 0,
              minRotation: 0
            },
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              callback: (value) => {
                return value.toFixed(this.activePairSettings.denominationCurrencyDisplayDecimalPlaces);
              }
            },
            position: 'right',
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: false,
              labelString: `Prices (${this.qc.toLocaleUpperCase()})`
            }
          }]
        },
        tooltips: {
          backgroundColor: '#007bff',
          intersect: false,
          displayColors: false,
          color: '#fff',
          mode: 'index',
          callbacks: {
            label: (tooltipItem, myData) => {
              // console.log('tooltipItem, myData', tooltipItem, myData)
              var label = myData.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

              if (label) {
                label += ': ';
              }
              // label += parseFloat(tooltipItem.value).toFixed(6);
              label += this.hs.bigNumberWithDecimalPrecision(tooltipItem.value, this.activePairSettings.denominationCurrencyDisplayDecimalPlaces).toString() + ` ${this.qc.toUpperCase()}`
              // console.log('label', label)
              return label;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="chart">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="chart-container">
                <canvas chart *ngIf="showChart" baseChart [options]="this.lineChartOptions" chartType="line"
                    [datasets]="lineChartDataSets" [plugins]="lineChartPlugins"  >
                </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to automatically show the tooltip for the latest line chart without the user page refresh

Comment: @HitechHitesh Basically, I want to open the tooltip on a specific point(in this case latestdata) without user hovering over that. This happens only once i.e  when chart data loaded. This help user letting knows that there is more info inside tooltip which opens on hover.

Comment: So what you can do is as the latest data in added into the table trigger the same thing that is done on page load for showing the tooltip  or you can get the tooltip into a variable then set it to show at that time by setting its value to show if possible

Comment: Ok, @HitechHitesh If you have some example/link to explain this, that will help.

Comment: For the tooltip what are you using which Library or the default of the line charts which has that

Comment: And add the html template in the question also

Comment: @HitechHitesh I am using the default tooltip of line charts. Added the html.

Comment: can you add the screen shot of how it looks

Comment: @HitechHitesh why you need the screenshots?